# Don't hide error on focus

Tags: jquery, devexpress-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc with unobtrusive validation to show the error messages on my model.  Also using the devexpress mvc helpers to build the razor views.  When doing a callback from a callbackpanel and it comes back with model errors the error messages show.  Because of the way we are making the calls the devexpress will not set focus to the control with error.  So I wrote function to find the control if it has errors and set the focus

```
function OncbpEndCallback(s, e) {
    var control = $("input[name='" + currentControl + "']");
    if (!HasError(currentControl)) {
        control = NextTabbable(control);
    }

    control.focus();
}
```

Problem is a lot of the time when I set focus it removes the validation message.  Not all the time but a lot of the time.  How can I prevent the message from going away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out using the [CustomValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) was the cause. As soon as I removed that from the model the error message didn't disappear.